# Regex for fixing URL patterns

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have the following url structure:

```
http://www.xyxyxyxyx.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=334
http://www.xyxyxyxyx.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=1094
```

and so on..

Recently I used IIS rewrite to rewrite this structure as

```
http://www.xyxyxyxyx.com/productcategory/334/my-product-url
http://www.xyxyxyxyx.com/productcategory/1094/some-other-product-url
```

and so on..

This works fine.

I want to create another rule so that if an invalid url requests comes with the following structure:

```
http://www.xyxyxyxyx.com/productcategory/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=334
```

the 'productcategory' part should be removed from the url and the url should look like

```
http://www.xyxyxyxyx.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=334
```

How do I write this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may vary depending on what you are using to apply the regex, but here's a basic one:

```
's|productcatgory/||'
```

If you want to make sure it also only does this when the xyxyxyxyx url is present, this should work:

```
's|^http://www\.xyxyxyxyx\.com/productcategory/|http://www\.xyxyxyxyx\.com/|'
```

Edit: Ah, so if productcategory could be any category, then you'll need to match around it, like so:

```
's|^http://www\.xyxyxyxyx\.com/.*/ShowProduct|http://www\.xyxyxyxyx\.com/ShowProduct|'
```

Comment: Thanks Drake, here 'productcategory' could be anything like cars, scooters, bikes etc, so how do I make it generic to pick up between 'http://www.xyxyxyxyx.com' and 'ShowProduct.aspx?ID=334'